# Open source Java Library for guitar chords detection when you play an mp3 music file

Tags: java, android

I am looking for an alternative in java as most of the libraries I found were written in c++
E.x. the clam library. http://clam-project.org/wiki/Chordata_tutorial

Does any body know a good java library which does pitch synthesis from a raw mp3 file and does chord matching afterwards based on some predefined algorithms?

I want to use it in android.

Comment: is solved if yes please share the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try using Android NDK and build and use clam with it.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html